# Add column with mapping through conditional formula with R

Tags: r, dataframe, mapping, conditional-operator

I have a problem that I want to solve through R but I can't find out how to do it or even whether it is actually possible.

My goal is to add a column to a 'Target' table through a 'Mapping' table that holds conditional formulas that should get evaluated to TRUE against the values in some of the columns of the 'Target' table.

The point is that I want that the user can update the formulas in the 'Mapping' table or even add some formulas without having to update the R code. So formulas need to get evaluated dynamically.

Let's see a concrete sample below to clarify this.
I have a 'Target' table as below:

```
Product    Customer  Quantity   Sales   Margin
Product 1   Customer 1  1000    15000   4.6%
Product 1   Customer 2  2000    30000   7.5%
Product 2   Customer 1  3000    60000   10%
Product 2   Customer 3  1500    30000   12%
Product 2   Customer 4  2000    40000   8%
```

I have a 'Mapping' table as below:

```
Condition                                           Method
Sales > 50000                                       Method 1
Sales < 50000 AND Margin < 5%                       Method 2
Sales < 50000 AND (Margin >= 5% AND Margin < 10%)   Method 3
Sales < 50000 AND Margin >= 10%                     Method 4
```

I assume that conditions are consistent and only one formula can evaluate to true for any combination of values in 'Target' table.

And I want to get the following result with the 'Method' column added to the 'Target' table :

```
Product     Customer    Quantity    Sales   Margin  Method
Product 1   Customer 1  1000    15000   4.6%    Method 2
Product 1   Customer 2  2000    30000   7.5%    Method 3
Product 2   Customer 1  3000    60000   10%     Method 1
Product 2   Customer 3  1500    30000   12%     Method 4
Product 2   Customer 4  2000    40000   8%      Method 3
```

My initial idea is to cross join the two tables and then to evaluate the formula in the 'Condition' table against the columns in the 'Target' table. Then I could only keep the rows where the condition evaluates to TRUE.

But I can't find out how to evaluate the 'Condition' formula dynamically against the other columns in the cross table.

I would then appreciate any idea/comment about this issue!

Any solution that would also include another way to express the 'Condition' formula would also be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Have a careful look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49266076/apply-data-frame-with-list-variable-of-multivariable-functions-to-a-data-frame-w and its answers. In principle you could adapt this to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Using `case_when` from the `dplyr` package would allow you to forgo using the "Mapping" dataframe. You can invoke the conditions directly:

```
library(dplyr)

Product <- c(1,1,2,2,2)
Customer <- c(1,2,1,3,4)
Quantity <- c(1000,2000,3000,1500,2000)
Sales <- c(15000,30000, 60000,30000,40000)
# For now, it's easier to work without percentage signs in "Margin"
Margin <- c(0.046, 0.075, 0.1, 0.12, 0.08) 

target_df <- data.frame(Product,Customer,Quantity,Sales,Margin)

target_df <- mutate(target_df,
                    Method = case_when(Sales > 50000 ~ "Method 1",
                                       Sales < 50000 &  Margin < 0.05 ~ "Method 2",
                                       Sales < 50000 & Margin >= 0.05 & Margin < 0.10 ~ "Method 3",
                                       Sales < 50000 & Margin >= 0.01 ~ "Method 4" ),
                    Margin = sprintf("%1.2f%%", 100*Margin) # We can re-add percentage signs here
                    )
```

Output:

```
  Product Customer Quantity Sales Margin   Method
1       1        1     1000 15000  4.60% Method 2
2       1        2     2000 30000  7.50% Method 3
3       2        1     3000 60000 10.00% Method 1
4       2        3     1500 30000 12.00% Method 4
5       2        4     2000 40000  8.00% Method 3
```